# Post with protobuf media formatters in net6

Tags: c#, .net, api, protobuf-net

I use protobuf for serializing on my API. I have the following test which fails with the following error `"Unsupported Media Type"`.

```cs
[Test]
public async Task PostPortfolioUsingProtoBuf()
{
    using (var testServer = TestServer.CreateTestServer())
    using (var client = testServer.CreateClient())
    {
        TestServer.SetupProtoBufClient(client);

        const string Route = "api/Portfolio/PostPortfolioProtoBuf/";

        var portfolio = new portfolio 
        {
            PortfolioId = "12345",
            PortfolioName = "TestPortfolio"
        };
        portfolio.AddSimulationsData(new[] { 1, 2, 3, 7, 5, 9 });
        portfolio.Type = "Generic";

        var stream = new MemoryStream { Position = 0 };
        Serializer.Serialize(stream, new List<Portfolio> { portfolio });
        stream.Position = 0;

        HttpContent content = new ByteArrayContent(stream.ToArray());

        var result = await client.PostAsync(Route, content).ConfigureAwait(false);

        Assert.That(result.IsSuccessStatusCode, Is.True, result.ReasonPhrase);
    }
}
```

The HttpClient using the same protobuf-net definitions that used to access the API and request the data with "application/x-protobuf".

```cs
[HttpPost("api/Portfolio/PostPortfolioSimulationsProtoBuf/")]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostWithProtoBuf(HttpRequestMessage message)
{
    var content = await message.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    var saveStream = new MemoryStream(content) { Position = 0 };
    await saveStream.FlushAsync();

    var portfolios= Serializer.Deserialize<List<Portfolio>>(saveStream);

    return this.Created("/api/portfolios/", portfolios);
}

public static class TestServer
{
    private static WebApplicationFactory<Program> testServer;

    public static WebApplicationFactory<Program> CreateTestServer()
    {
        return
            new WebApplicationFactory<Program>()
                .WithWebHostBuilder(builder =>
                    builder
                        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()));
    }

    public static void SetupProtoBufClient(HttpClient client)
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-protobuf"));
    }
}
```

I have configured the program.cs with:

```cs
builder.Services.AddControllers(options =>
{
    options.FormatterMappings.SetMediaTypeMappingForFormat("protobuf", MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/x-protobuf"));
}).AddProtobufFormatters();
```

Any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: The body of the HTTP Request is not matching the schema.  Read following : https://techkranti.com/what-is-protobuf-explained-for-hackers/?force_isolation=true